# CountDownTimer does not stop when calling cancel() method

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple game called "The Amazing Race".
Overview of the program: A program which has three animals participating in the race, including pig, chicken and turtle, will let players guess which animal will win in the race.
However, I am struggling in cancel() method of CountDownTimer Object. I cannot understand why the cancel() method did not work (Even though one of the animals get to the destination, but the other two still run to the end)

```
                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 300) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Random rd = new Random();

                        if (skbGa.getProgress() >= skbGa.getMax()) {
                            this.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gà thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if (skbLon.getProgress() >= skbLon.getMax()) {
                            this.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lợn thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if (skbRua.getProgress() >= skbRua.getMax()) {
                            this.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rùa thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        skbGa.setProgress(skbGa.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                        skbLon.setProgress(skbLon.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                        skbRua.setProgress(skbRua.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                };

                countDownTimer.start();
```

The entire code of my program

```
package quynhanhhle.theamazingrace;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtDiem;
    CheckBox chkGa, chkRua, chkLon;
    SeekBar skbGa, skbRua, skbLon;
    ImageButton btnBatDau;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        anhXa();

        xuLyCheckBox();

        chuongTrinhChinh();

        choiLai();
    }

    private void choiLai() {
        btnBatDau.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        chkRua.setEnabled(true);
        chkLon.setEnabled(true);
        chkGa.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void chuongTrinhChinh() {
        btnBatDau.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(chkLon.isChecked() || chkGa.isChecked() || chkRua.isChecked())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Đoán con vật chiến thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    btnBatDau.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    chkGa.setEnabled(false);
                    chkLon.setEnabled(false);
                    chkRua.setEnabled(false);

                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 300) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            Random rd = new Random();

                            if (skbGa.getProgress() >= skbGa.getMax()) {
                                this.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gà thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            if (skbLon.getProgress() >= skbLon.getMax()) {
                                this.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lợn thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            if (skbRua.getProgress() >= skbRua.getMax()) {
                                this.cancel();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rùa thắng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            skbGa.setProgress(skbGa.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                            skbLon.setProgress(skbLon.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                            skbRua.setProgress(skbRua.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {

                        }
                    };

                    countDownTimer.start();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void xuLyCheckBox() {
        chkGa.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chkGa.isChecked()){
                    chkLon.setChecked(false);
                    chkRua.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

        chkLon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chkLon.isChecked()){
                    chkGa.setChecked(false);
                    chkRua.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

        chkRua.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chkRua.isChecked()){
                    chkGa.setChecked(false);
                    chkLon.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void anhXa() {

        txtDiem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDiem);

        chkGa = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkGa);

        chkLon = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkLon);

        chkRua = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRua);

        skbGa = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbGa);

        skbLon = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbLon);

        skbRua = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbRua);

        btnBatDau = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBatDau);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `btnBatDau.setOnClickListener` is being fired more than once? Try checking if `countDownTimer` is not running before creating it.

Comment: What do you mean by "fired" ? I tried to read android documentation about CountDownTimer and it also has this word and I do not catch the idea of this.

Comment: I'm not native english speaker, but as far as i know `fired` is something like `called` (in code)

Comment: I got your idea

Comment: Your code seems to work. Are you sure `countDownTimer` is still running? Or `onTick` just gets called one more time?

Comment: I run the program on the actual device and the countDownTimer is still running. And the program only ends when the three animals go to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating a new countDownTimer each time btnBatDau is clicked.

My suggestion is put the countDownTimer initialization block to your Activity's onCreate().

There is no problem with calling `CountDownTimer#cancel()` (or `this.cancel()` in your example.) It cancels the timer and onTick() won't be called.

See this example. It cancels correctly:

```
 CountDownTimer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(millisUntilFinished < 5000) {
                    this.cancel();
                }

                Log.d("Timer", millisUntilFinished + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
```

The Log output is the following:

```
09-08 17:48:10.627 21140-21140/com.safaorhan.coundownsample D/Timer: 8954
09-08 17:48:11.629 21140-21140/com.safaorhan.coundownsample D/Timer: 7953
09-08 17:48:12.630 21140-21140/com.safaorhan.coundownsample D/Timer: 6952
09-08 17:48:13.631 21140-21140/com.safaorhan.coundownsample D/Timer: 5950
09-08 17:48:14.633 21140-21140/com.safaorhan.coundownsample D/Timer: 4949
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should copy `countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer... public void onFinish() {};` into onCreate() ?

Comment: Yes, you should move it to onCreate. Then in your button's onClickListener you can start your timer if you want.

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not stop. I do not catch the idea of  "creating a new CountDownTimer each time the btnBatDau is clicked". Can you help me with this?

Comment: I mean that the btnBatDau can not be clicked more than once before the game ends because I have set it invisible, so it cannot interact with players during the game.

Comment: You don't need multiple instances of countDownTimer. Every time you press the button you are creating an instance of it

Comment: to my knowledge, the button of the code I wrote above can only be clicked once in a game (before the countDownTimer is created)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own timer like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2;
    Button start;

    Handler handler;
    Runnable timer;
    boolean running;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);
        seekBar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek2);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_timer);

        start.setOnClickListener(startrListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener startListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startTimer();
        }
    };

    private void startTimer() {
        handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!running) return;

                Random rd = new Random();

                if (seekBar1.getProgress() >= seekBar1.getMax())
                    stopTimer();
                if (seekBar2.getProgress() >= seekBar2.getMax())
                    stopTimer();

                seekBar1.setProgress(seekBar1.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));
                seekBar2.setProgress(seekBar2.getProgress() + (rd.nextInt(10) + 1));

                handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(timer, 300);
        running = true;
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        running = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(timer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I still want to know the problem from my code. But thank you, I will try this.